# Clarification on comparing == functions and memory location

Tags: python, function, memory-address

I have some questions/clarifications to ask regarding the code snippet below. Thank you!

```
cube_a = 2 ** 3
cube_b = 2 ** 3
cube_c = lambda x: x ** 3
cube_d = lambda x: x ** 3
cube_e = lambda x: cube_d
cube_f = lambda cube_d: cube_d
def cube_g(cube_a):
    def cube_h(cube_a):
        return cube_a ** 3
    return cube_h

print(cube_d == cube_e(2)) #True Statement 1
print(cube_d == cube_f(2)) #False Statement 2
print(cube_g(3)(5) == 5 **3 ) #True Statement 3
print(cube_a== cube_b) #True Statement 4
print(cube_c== cube_d) #False Statement 5
```

I do not understand why statement 1 is true, below is my understanding for the rest of the statements.

Statement 2: a function and another function that `return` that former function are different

Regarding statement 3: `cube_g(3)(5)` becomes `cube_g(3)` which calls `cube_h(5)` hence returning `5**3`

Regarding statement 4: is it true because the functions/code are exactly the same line by line? I tried switching up the order (2 **3 vs 3 **2) and using the `id()` the address was different.

Regarding statement 5: Every lambda function has its own address?

Comment: `cube_e` ignores its input and returns the unevaluated `cube_d`. It *doesn't* forward its input to `cube_d`. Thus, `cube_d == cube_e(2)` is of course true since `cube_e` simply returns `cube_d`. In any event -- this question is rather broad. It would be better to pick one question at a time.

Comment: The `cube_d` in `cube_f` has nothing to do with the function you named `cube_d`. Naming a function parameter the same thing as a global variable hides the global variable in that function. It doesn't link the global and the parameter together in some way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement 1 is true because in `cube_e` you are just returning the lambda function itself, you are not passing any arguments so it will always return `cube_d`